# Is there a way to calculate the number of digits of an integer in binary with recursion?

Tags: python, recursion, binary

So I want to make a version of this function, but this time using recursion:

```
def binary_length(natural):
res = 1
while natural >= 2:
    res += 1
    natural //= 2
return res
```

My take at this is:

```
def binary_length_recursive(natural):
    res = 1
    while natural >= 2:
        res += 1
        natural //= 2
    if res%2==0:
        return res
    else:
        return binary_length_recursive(natural)
```

I have seen the recommended articles , but they aren't much help to my case.

Comment: Please provide the expected see [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
We expect a minimal working example of the problem, including appropriate code to trace the internal operation.

Comment: Very simply,  you haven't demonstrated any problem: your posted code is never called, you have no output, etc.  I don't follow how your algorithm is supposed to work.  In more simple terms, why not simply convert it to a binary string and take the length?

Answer (score 2):

The idea of a recursive function is that the recursion is itself the loop.

You know that 0 and 1 have 1 digit, and you know that the rest of the number is represented by dividing by 2.  Hence:

```
>>> def binary_length(n):
...     if n <= 1:
...         return 1
...     return 1 + binary_length(n//2)
...
```

Testing it out:

```
>>> [(n, binary_length(n)) for n in range(10)]
[(0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 2), (4, 3), (5, 3), (6, 3), (7, 3), (8, 4), (9, 4)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the function with the number divided by two again.

```py
def binary_length(number):
    if number < 2:
        return 1
    return 1 + binary_length(number // 2)
```